# How far can a knight travel without visiting the same square twice?

Tags: chess, puzzles

How many Knight moves is it possible to execute on an empty chess board before the Knight lands on a square it has already landed on in its previous moves?  The most I've ever been able to land on was 54 squares, usually 50-52.

Comment: Meta discussion migrated here: http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/492/is-this-puzzle-on-topic

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a famous puzzle called the [Knight's Tour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight%27s_tour) in which the aim is to visit every square exactly once.  Since this has several solutions, the answer to your question is that it can visit all 64 squares.

Comment: Questions are expected to relate to board games. (This one barely is.) They shouldn't be "too local," but chess is a global game. They are expected to have a reasonably objective answer acceptable to most people, which I believe this one does.If you want to know whether this, or any other question is on/off topic, the place to ask is on meta.

Comment: Ok, thanks; I wasn't sure who to ask.  Sorry for the newbie-ness!

Comment: Thanks for the link!  The animated wikipedia solution is not intuitively obvious.